# Design add-on base Application

Tags: c#, .net, add-on

I want to know that how design application , actually applications like Firefox or Chrome that you can download add-on for them and use ??!!
How do it in .Net ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to allow others to make Add-Ons for your app?

1>You create a `DLL` which has an `interface`.This `interface` defines a set of methods,properties,events you want others to define and implement.

the plugin developer need to define this interface.This DLL is required by your app and the plugin developer..

2>The plugin developer would use that shared `DLL` and implement the interface by defining the methods or properties in it.

3>Your app would now load that plugin and cast it to the shared DLL's `interface` and then call the desired methods,properties i.e anything that was defined in the interface..

How would your App fetch plugins?

You create a `folder` where you would search for the `plugins`.This is the folder where others `plugins` would be `installed` or `placed`.

---

Example

This is your shared dll

```
//this is the shared plugin
namespace Shared 
{
    interface IWrite 
    {
        void write();
    }
}
```

The plugin devloper

```
//this is how plugin developer would implement the interface
using Shared;//<-----the shared dll is included
namespace PlugInApp 
{
    public class plugInClass : IWrite //its interface implemented
    {
        public  void write() 
        {
            Console.Write("High from plugInClass");
        }
    }
}
```

this is your program

```
using Shared;//the shared plugin is required for the cast
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //this is how you search in the folder
            foreach (string s in Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "*PlugIn.dll"))//getting plugins in base directory ending with PlugIn.dll
            {
                Assembly aWrite = Assembly.LoadFrom(s);
                //this is how you cast the plugin with the shared dll's interface
                Type tWrite = aWrite.GetType("PlugInApp.plugInClass");
                IWrite click = (IWrite)Activator.CreateInstance(tWrite);//you create the object
                click.write();//you call the method
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: nice done, could you clear me ,for example I developed accounting software by vb.net and I want to add backup feature to take backup  from its sql database by adding plugin to my applcation ,so how should I come up with that?

Comment: @franchescototti you would have to make some changes to your accounting app to implement the plugin search and execute functionality..

Comment: if you know any sample for windows form app please let me know ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF).

http://mef.codeplex.com/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use MEF.

> The Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF) is a new library in .NET
>   that enables greater reuse of applications and components. Using MEF,
>   .NET applications can make the shift from being statically compiled to
>   dynamically composed. If you are building extensible applications,
>   extensible frameworks and application extensions, then MEF is for you.

useful link for MEF.

http://mef.codeplex.com/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/376033/From-Zero-to-Proficient-with-MEF

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/232868/MEF-Features-with-Examples